# Excel formula doesn't work for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I did this formula to get a percentage of wrong documents / all the documents:

`=SUM(COUNTIF(F5:M5; {"*Pending*";"*Rejected*";"*Expired*";"*Empty*"})) / COUNTIF(F5:M5;"<>*N/A*")`

The thing is I want this formula to be a conditional formatting for the whole column, but I get this error:

`You may not use reference operators such as unions intersections and ranges, array constants or the lambda function.`

Any way to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Count the good ones and work the difference...

Comment: The formula works fine, the problem is when I use this formula to a conditional formatting, something i'm doing is not allowed.

Comment: I think it's because you are using `{"*Pending*";"*Rejected*";"*Expired*";"*Empty*"}`. What if you do a single countif for each one, and sum them up?

Comment: And how can I concat `COUNTIF()`'s? I mean `=SUM(COUNTIF(F5:M5; "*Pending*") AND COUNTIF(F5:M5; "*Expired*"))`. Like this?

Comment: Something like `SUM(COUNTIF(F5:M5; "*Pending*")+COUNTIF(F5:M5; "*Rejected*")+COUNTIF(F5:M5; "*Expired*")+COUNTIF(F5:M5; "*Empty*"))` probably

Comment: But I tought cells will be filled with the conditional formatting... I have an Excel template (.xltx), and what I'm trying to achieve is to still get my formulas working when getting .xlsx files from it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Instead of checking `<>*N/A*`, you might use the function `IfNA()`.
2. What kind of conditional formatting are you using? Some are switches (put a colour or not), and some are progressable (like changing colour bars).

For the switches, you need a formula which gives `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: 1. It is a value "N/A", like "Rejected". My conditional will be if percentage is not 0 then font colour will be red.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array constants in CF formula, but you can enter that constants in some range and use range in formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(F2:M2;$T$2:$T$5)) / COUNTIF(F2:M2;"<>*N/A*")
```

[image]

Comment: But how can you save that formula if you have and Excel template (.xltx), and you want the formula to still working in it's xlsx files? Because a conditional formatting is not putting values in the column.

Comment: @Martinez Are there any problems entering values and saving them with the template?